# TypeORM save throws error: the incoming request has too many parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, save, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with SQL Server database for a NodeJS application and when I try to bulk save large array of data (200+ objects), it throws the following error. I tried using the `chunk` option but without success.

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.

What am I doing wrong?

```
let csvDataArr = data.map(record => {
    return {
        itemType: parseInt(record['itemType']),
        dateTime: !isNaN(Date.parse(record['dateTime'])) ? new Date(record['dateTime']) : null,
        barcode: record['barcode'],
        description: record['description'],
        specialInformation: record['specialInformation'],
        signedBy: record['signedBy'],
        location: record['location'],
        locationExternalReference: record['locationExternalReference'],
        scanLatitude: record['scanLatitude'],
        scanLongitude: record['scanLongitude'],
        clientSpecificOrderRef: record['clientSpecificOrderRef'],
        deliveryID: record['deliveryID']
    }
})

return await this.repo.save(csvDataArr, { chunk: 500 });
```

Comment: You say you have 200+ objects, but you specify `{ chunk: 500 }` so it will be trying to insert 500 at a time. I expect if you capture the query in SQL Profiler or Extended Events that TypeORM is probably not using bulk inserts, but inserting multiple rows using a pattern similar to `INSERT tableName (Columns) VALUES (...), (...), ... ,(...)`. Have you tried specifying a smaller `chunk` size?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `data` is a dynamic array. I'm running that code in a for loop and on each iteration I tried giving it the actual length: `{ chunk: csvDataArr.length }` but without success. I tried hardcoding a smaller `chunk` size like 20 but also without success.

Comment: You probably need to investigate what's going on with SQL Profiler or Extended Events, as in capture the query that it's actually trying to execute. If my suspicion is correct about what's going on then inserting 12-column rows using `VALUES` and parameters gives you a budget of about 175 rows before it hits the limit of 2100 parameters. It should have worked with 20, though, so don't know what's going on there.

Comment: My bad, it worked with 20 and even 100. Thanks for your help! Pasted one of the rows SQL Profiler outputed https://pastebin.com/7YCKgfEv